# Join a table with a string value in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have been given a database. In this database is a table called Example that looks like this:

```
ID    EntityName    EntityID
1     Foo           1
2     Bar           1
3     Foo           2
4     Bar           2
```

The EntityName and EntityID column combine to make a foreign key to either a Foo or an Bar table. If the EntityName field is 'Foo', EntityID refers to FooID in the Foo table. Sadly, the structure of the database is not to be altered. My question:

**Can I create a Linq query that only joins the needed table based on the value of EntityName?**

I'm looking for something like this:

```
from e in examples
join table in [e.EntityName] ON e.EntityID equals table.([EntityID] + "ID")
// etc
```

Can it be done?

Comment: What would you expect the SQL to look like?

Comment: I would add a subquery that gets the value of the EntityName column, and then an if/else to decide what table gets joined. Not a pretty solution, but it could work. On a sidenote, you've answered one of my previous questions very well. As a result, I started reading your book in the hopes of working my way up to your skill level. Thanks for the continued help!

Comment: That subquery might start looking pretty interesting... I suspect you may well end up needing to effectively do a three way join with some dummy values. I can imagine what the LINQ *might* look like, but I've no idea whether or not it would actually work...

Comment: how many columns can table have?  it must be a distinct number -- this is the number of joins you would need, you then "merge" the results with a coalesce -- unless you are using dynamic sql -- none of this makes sense in linq.

Comment: Do you mean how many distinct values can appear in EntityName? At the moment there's only 2 possible values.

Comment: ah I see I miss read it with the strange [] syntax... I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the number of values of Name.

Since you have 2 you use a union... like this:

```
var result = 
(from e in examples
 where e.EntityName == "Foo"
 join foos in foo ON e.EntityID equals foo.fooID
)

.Union

(from e in examples
 where e.EntityName == "Bar"
 join bars in bar ON e.EntityID equals bar.barID
);
```

It seems like there is "extra" here and it will be slower, but this should result in an effient SQL statement using `UNION ALL`

Comment: LINQ will not let you union types that don't match. I would assume Foo and Bar are different types in the OP. Perhaps if they shared a common base class it might be possible to use union. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @BradD bad assumption.  In every case of a data model like this I've seen they are basically the same or can be "cast" or have a sub-set selected which is the same types.  The OP didn't let us know those details so we have to assume his question is solvable.

Comment: No better or worse than the assumption that they can be cast. Perhaps clarification from the OP is in order.

Comment: Thanks! I left work, so won't be able to try until Monday, but know that I will definitely try your solution after the weekend!